# Is there a possibility of VAC ban because of using Tunngle?

Tags: steam

Tunngle creates virtual LAN network and let gamers play with remotely located friends via LAN. So is this possible to get VAC ban (on VAC enabled games) if we use Tunngle with steam ?

"Playing multi-player mods which do not modify core .EXE and .DLL files" clause was previously mentioned at [steam vac](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7849-Radz-6869) page according to [answer to the question about how VAC works](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/3640/125599) but as you can see. This clause has been removed. So I am confused.

**Update: Valve response**

> We do not provide analysis of third party software for VAC compliance.
>   Any third party software, skins or other modifications you use in
>   conjunction with Steam should be done at your own discretion.
>
> Only cheats (modifications designed to give one player an advantage
>   over other players) will trigger a VAC ban.

[image]

Comment: I'm unsure how the vac system works but using a software to emulate a LAN over internet is usually not something that is considered as cheating, doubt you'll get banned for that.

Comment: The only ones who can answer this is Valve themselves. Asking us to interpret clauses is going to be, at best, a guess.

Comment: @Frank I disagree; I think it's fairly obvious that a networking software like Tunngle is not designed to give one player an advantage over another player, and furthermore, the VAC system doesn't secure LAN games, only servers with VAC enabled.

Comment: Unless your VPN is somehow editing the game traffic passing through it, there's no way VAC would even know, let alone have a problem with you using it.

Comment: @Unionhawk Okay. How are you going to go about proving that? Interpreting clauses that do or do not exist is going to be a crap shoot.

Comment: @Frank is there another interpretation of the words "Any third-party modification to a game designed to give one player an advantage over another“ that I'm unaware of?

Comment: @Unionhawk Is there a different intrepretation of, "Exercise in mind reading" that I'm unaware of?

Comment: @Frank This isn't an exercise in mind reading. It's an exercise in... well, reading. The VAC system only detects modifications to a game designed to give the player an advantage. Not only is the software in question not designed to give the player an advantage, it isn't a modification to the game. Furthermore, [just because we cannot technically *prove* something does not mean it's automatically a question about developer intent](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/is-this-question-requires-developer-only-knowledge-the-same-thing-as-developer)

Comment: @Unionhawk We're going to have to agree to disagree.

Comment: Voting to leave open. We should not assume what is within the knowledge of other users just because of our own closed mind. There is a few more meta posts I've seen that argue this well, @Unionhawk, but I feel at this point, linking them would be redundant.

Comment: @Frank I have already raised a support ticket on steam. I will post their official reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can only get VAC banned by playing games that are VAC enabled, which you wouldn't need Tunngle for anyway.
Tunngle is basically a VPN software and does not modify any game related files, so there is no way it would be detected as a cheating software.

Comment: More specifically, servers that are VAC secured. Some TF2 servers for example are not.

Comment: You are wrong. I live in a country where there are no official servers of steam. We just have few community servers of our own which are not enough. So most people use Virtual LAN either because they can't port forward due to ISP restriction. Or they can't host a dedicated server

Comment: Lets take an example of CS GO. Nearest official servers are minimum 200ms away. 200+ ping is quite a lot. So for low latency, some people prefer tunngle.